# Parse WHERE condition with regular expressions

Tags: sql, regex

I was wondering if anyone can help me with a regular expression - not my strongest point - to parse the WHERE part of a SQL statement. I need to extract the column names, either in "column" or "table.column" format. I'm using MySQL and PHP.

For example, parsing:

```
(table.column_a = '1') OR (table.column_a = '0')) 
AND (date_column < '2014-07-03') 
AND column_c LIKE '%my search string%'
```

should yield

```
table.column_a
table.column_b
date_column
column_c
```

Edit: clarification - the strings will be parsed in PHP with preg_* functions!

Thank you!

Comment: What engine will you use to parse the SQL? Not an SQL engine, right?

Comment: I will parse this in PHP!

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you need to parse that?

Comment: Given the number of possible expressions that can contain a column name in a WHERE clause (sometimes in a nested fashion), I don't think you can ever get something that works all the time using only regexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are not doing this in SQL, you can use a regex like this:

```
[A-Za-z._]+(?=[ ]*(?:[<>=]|LIKE))
```

See [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/4).

This would work in Notepad++ and many languages.

**Explanation**

- `[A-Za-z._]+` matches the characters in your word (if you want to add digits, add `0-9`
- The lookahead `(?=[ ]*(?:[<>=]|LIKE))` asserts that what follows is optional spaces (the brackets are optional, they make the space stand out), then one of the characters in this class `[<>=]` (an operator OR `|` `LIKE`
- You can add operators inside `[<>=]`, or  tag them at the end with another alternation, e.g. `|REGEXP`

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this will fail whenever you put column names on the right side of operators, or use them in function calls, or in CASE WHEN clauses, etc...